# How do you access the children of a WPF Canvas class?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

How do you access the children of a WPF Canvas class?

It is a cool class and I like how you are able to add children.  But once they are there, how to you look at them for reading their state and content.  I know it is easy if you put the children in XAML.  But what if you have added children to the canvas dynamically at run time?

Comment: Canvas has a Children collection. Does this not work for you?

Comment: What is the menber of the canvas class that indicates the number of children?  Something like canvas.amount, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx) property.

---

Edit: Here is an example of iterating over the children and getting one by index:

```
foreach (UIElement child in canvas.Children)
{
    // ...
}
// Or: 
int index = 0;
var childByIndex = canvas.Children[index];
```

Comment: I saw that but it only talks about Adding the Children, not viewing them.

Comment: @xarzu: UIElementCollection implements IList, so you can enumerate it using Linq or a foreach loop and you can get children by index using the indexer.

Comment: What is the menber of the canvas class that indicates the number of children?  Something like canvas.amount, for example.

Comment: @xarzu: canvas.Children.Count